# Starting a new indented paragraph after an equation

Tags: paragraphs

What is the recommended way to start a new indented paragraph after an equation?

Example 1:

```
We end the paragraph with the following equation:
$$ a + b = c. $$

In this new paragraph, we will show...
```

Example 2:

```
We end the paragraph with the following equation:
$$ a + b = c. $$
\indent In this new paragraph, we will show...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is LaTeX, the recommended way is

```
We end the paragraph with the following equation:
\[a + b = c.\]

In this new paragraph, we will show...
```

You should never need to use `\indent` in LaTeX, and if you do not add the blank line then it does not start a new paragraph, it just adds an empty indentation box as if a paragraph started.

The space added before paragraphs would be a document-wide setting so set in code that you have not shown.

(If you are using plain TeX, the answer would be the same, but using `$$` rather than `\[`)

Comment: I want the horizontal indentation. If what you write is the recommended way, then there is really no possibility to distinguish a new paragraph after an equation inside the definition environment from the end of the definition environment in terms of the vertical space? As I wrote above, if I do not italicize definitions, I find it confusing. Maybe I shall not use paragraphs in definitions at all?

Comment: @Pavel you have provided no usable example so it is impossible to see what spacing you are getting and what spacing you have specified around a paragraph. You presumably get the same issue for any multi-paragraph definition text, how do you show the end of the definition? If you edited your question to show an example of the problem then more specific advice on what to change could be given. (Questions should almost always have a complete small document, not just a fragment as an example)

Comment: OK, sorry, I will edit the question in a second.

Comment: In your edit please make it clear if the problem is just for paragraphs following an equation or for any multi-paragraph  text in a definition.

Comment: In the end, I removed the additional comments from my question. I realized that my problem was merely the fact that both equations and definitions are already vertically indented and that setting parskip manually to a higher value and adding a new paragraph after an equation inside a definition made the vertical space after the equation bigger than the vertical space below the definition. I should rethink the design of my document. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Pavel If you have non zero `\parindent` then `\parskip` should be zero!  (which is why I queried your initial statement about vertical space) Certainly in European typesetting tradition, although by coincidence it came up in chat last week that Indian tradition would have both non zero in some cases)